# Access: automatically enter date in one field when another field updates

Tags: ms-access

I have a field with different status options which is being updated regularly by many people. I want the field next to it show the date when the last change has been done to the status field.
I am fairly new to access, so I'm not sure if this is a very basic thing that I'm missing.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a `BeforeChange` Data Macro. You can use the `old` table to see the previous value of your Status field and `Status` to see the current. If they are different then that field has changed and you can change your date modified

[image]

You can either make that yourself or try to copy and paste the XML into the MacroEditor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
    <DataMacro Event="BeforeChange">
        <Statements>
            <ConditionalBlock>
                <If>
                    <Condition>[Old].[Status]&lt;&gt;[Status]</Condition>
                    <Statements>
                        <Action Name="SetField">
                            <Argument Name="Field">DateStatusModified</Argument>
                            <Argument Name="Value">Now()</Argument>
                        </Action>
                    </Statements>
                </If>
            </ConditionalBlock>
        </Statements>
    </DataMacro>
</DataMacros>
```

The advantage to this method is that it will execute this logic if someone makes the change directly in the table, or another form, or another program.

Answer (score 0):

Rather basic. :) You need an `AfterUpdate` event procedure:

```
Private Sub StatusField_AfterUpdate()
    ' Set your date field to the current date. Use "= Now" to include time information.
    Me!DateLog = Date
End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't you use the BeforeUpdate event?

Comment: No - if the user decides he wants to undo the change with Esc (while still in the StatusField), I don't want to have already set the log date. @Gustav

Comment: True, but if the user presses Esc before leaving _StatusField_, there is no update and _BeforeUpdate_ will not fire. If _StatusField_ has been left and it and _DateLog_ have been updated, both updates will be cancelled if the user presses Esc to cancel the update of the record.